# Show that, in $C[0,1]$, the functions with $f(\Bbb Q) \subseteq \Bbb Q$ are dense.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, function-spaces

For $C[0,1]$ the space of all continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$,

Show that, in $C[0,1]$, the functions with $f(\mathbb{Q})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ are dense.

I'm having trouble understanding what dense means in relation to functions, so am not sure how to answer this! Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It could mean the following: for every function $f \in C[0, 1]$, show that there exist functions $g, h$ with $g(x) < f(x) < h(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, such that both $g(\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ and $h(\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: For precision's sake, I think you both mean $f(\Bbb Q\cap[0,1])\subseteq\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

A subset $A\subseteq C[0,1]$ of functions is called dense in $C[0,1]$
if
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0 \,\forall g\in C[0,1]\, \exists h \in A:
\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |h(x)-g(x)|< \varepsilon.
$$
In your case, the set $A$ would be
$$
A=\{f\in C[0,1] | f(\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]) \subseteq \Bbb Q \}.
$$

Comment: And why is it dense?